# How to link against a static library which uses static libraries itself using scons and Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static-libraries, scons

My SConstruct file looks something like this:

```
jnglLibs = Split("freetype png ogg vorbisfile") # left out a few
env.Library(target="jngl", source=source_files, LIBS=jnglLibs)
env.Program("test.cpp", LIBS=Split("jngl") + jnglLibs)
```

The static library links fine but the program fails with unresolved external symbols from the libraries in jnglLibs.

```
lib /nologo /OUT:jngl.lib finally.obj freetype.obj main.obj opengl.obj sprite.ob
j tess.obj texture.obj window.obj windowptr.obj callbacks.obj ConvertUTF.obj aud
io.obj win32\message.obj win32\time.obj win32\window.obj
cl /Fotest.obj /c test.cpp /TP /nologo /EHsc /MD -O2 -DNDEBUG /I.
test.cpp
link /OUT:test.exe /LIBPATH:. /LIBPATH:lib jngl.lib freetype.lib png.lib opengl3
2.lib glu32.lib user32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib z.lib jpeg.lib dl.lib openal32.
lib alut.lib ogg.lib vorbisfile.lib test.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

jngl.lib(freetype.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol FT_Done_FreeT
ype referenced in function "public: __cdecl jngl::Font::~Font(void)" (??1Font@jn
gl@@QEAA@XZ)
... and so on
```

Why doesn't it find the symbol FT_Done_FreeType which is in freetype.lib? It works perfectly with GCC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of quirks with static linking on Windows.. I've had one or two similar problems to this but mostly my problem was once the 'static' libs were compiled they still depended on the .dll's being there.  Anyway, I've been feeling your pain for a while now but got through it for my purposes... here's one page that really helped me.

http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/tutorial2/libxslt_pipes.html#windows-build

It doesn't have to do with those particular libraries you listed but it might give you some clues.  One thing is figuring out which C-runtime library each of those .libs (or '_a.libs,' which you might want to look into) were compiled against and make sure they are all the same when you statically link.  So since you're using /MD, make sure all those libs were also compiled with /MD and not /MT.  That COULD be a reason it isn't finding that freetype symbol, but it's just one guess.  Good luck!